# MS SQL select-where on unicode string-equality fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running this query and it is not returning any record , but in actual the record is exists. My record is all full of Chinese character.

My Query is

```
SELECT * FROM Users U WHERE NickUser = N'你好12345' AND Password = '1234567'
```

The NickUser is a `NVARCHAR` type and the NickUser 你好12345 is really in my table.

Is that any setting issue i left out ?? or there is problem with my query ?

Comment: try like operator instead??

Comment: Well, maybe the password is different ;)

Comment: @ Shakeer Mirza: like for passwords? now why would that be a bad idea!

Comment: also: why are you storing passwords in plain text?

Comment: because this is a test table for me to try with Chinese character

Comment: Are you sure that there is no invisible character, maybe from copy/paste? Try: `SELECT * FROM Users U WHERE NickUser LIKE N'%你好12345%'`

Comment: May be the 'collation' issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is invisible character in your database. Investigate that data using like operator, select values with its length to see, if visible characters count is the same as stored characters count.